# I wonder why I get the address of L instead of the value?

Tags: java

public class SLList {
    public IntNode first;//create a 64 bits space for first as a type of IntNode

```
public SLList(int x) {
    first = new IntNode(x, null);
} 

public void addFirst(int x) {
    first = new IntNode(x, first);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SLList L = new SLList(10);
    L.addFirst(10);
    System.out.println(L);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`System.out.println(L)` will call the toString() method on the parameter (`L` in this case). Since `L` is a class rather than a `String`, the default toString() method prints `ClassName@HashCode`. If you want a textual representation of the contents in `L` you'll want to override the toString() method:

```java
public class SLList {
    ...
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Overridden toString()";
    }
    ...
```

Then `System.out.println(L)` will print `Overridden toString()`.